# Can I change pattern permissions after initial setup of the Dream Suite?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I opened up my Dream Suite today, and during the intial setup, Luna asked me if I wanted to make my patterns publicly available so people can download them or if I wanted to make it so people could view them only.

I chose to share them, thinking that if I ever changed my mind, I'd be able to go back and change the setting.

However, in exploring the various dialog options with Luna, I can't seem to find a way to do this. I see that I can still change whether my Dream Address is public on my TPC, or even choose to delete my dream entirely, but not anything about the patterns.

If I choose to share or not share my pattern/designs, am I stuck with that decision? Can you change it by deleting and remaking your dream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not stuck with your initial decision!

Luna lets you know that you can update your Dream once a day (and only once a day) to update the version of your town that everyone else sees. After speaking with her today and confirming with her that I wanted to update my Dream, she asked me again about whether or not I wanted to make my patterns/designs publicly available.

So there's no need to delete and remake your Dream if you're worried about this, as every time you update it, you'll be able to choose your preferred setting.